# An error occurs when creating TextEditingController object

Tags: flutter

I have a question
An error occurs when creating an object as shown below.

ex)

```
  final TextEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

error message is this:

```
Only static members can be accessed in initializers.
```

I am curious about the cause of this error and how to fix it

thank you for let me know ~!

[image: error message capture]

Comment: if you feel like my answer was the right answer for you, feel free to accept it as the correct answer. I hope you enjoy flutter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error here is that you forgot to name your variable. You defined that it is `final` of type `TextEditingController` but didn't name the variable. In your case, the fix would be (just a suggestion on the variable name: `_controller`)

```
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```